# XML schema restrictions

Tags: xml

Is there anyway to restrict an XML file so it contains only letters, up and lower case and many words?

For example I tried this:

```
<xs:element name="environment">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]*"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

But now I can add only one word, I want to add many.

The XML may look like this:

```
<environment>Many words but no numbers or anything.</environment>
```

Comment: Just add space and full stop to the list of allowed characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:element name="environment">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:list>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
          <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

But the period in your sample sentence is not allowed.

Comment: OK, How can I do many words and a period :)  Main problem is that I can make only one word with that restriction.

Comment: @user1876942 Add the period as the last optional part of the word, e.g. `[a-zA-z]*\.?`